# How to make custom WordPress footer centered on mobile

Tags: php, css, wordpress, formatting

I'm wondering if I can put any @media CSS code to make this work, or any advise on how I can go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the `padding-left:200px` in `.nonprofit` is causing the problem. Try to remove it.

Comment: I was trying to make the text and the image on the same line, but this works too!

Answer (score 0):

Use padding-left: 10px;

It's not a good practice to remove all the time! you can set a lower value like 0px or 10px that's the same result.

```
<div <?php echo mesmerize_footer_container( 'footer-simple' ) ?>>
    <div <?php echo mesmerize_footer_background( 'footer-content center-xs' ) ?>>
        <div class="gridContainer">
            <div class="row middle-xs footer-content-row">
                <div class="footer-content-col col-xs-12">
                    <?php
echo ' 
<html>


<style>
.nonprofit {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 15px;
color: white;
padding-left: 10px;
display: block;
align: right;
}
</style>
<p class="nonprofit"> © 2019 Veterans for Diversity, Inc.</br>Veterans for Diversity, Inc.® is a tax-exempt 501(C)(3) nonprofit organization.</p>
<style>
.nonprofit {
float: left;
}
</style>
<div class="nonprofit">
<a href="https://uwm.edu/informationstudies/nonprofit/" target="_blank"><img src="https://veterans4diversity.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/nonprof-IT_icon.jpg" alt="UWM-NonProfIT" width="200" height="55" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-234" srcset="https://veterans4diversity.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/nonprof-IT_icon.jpg, https://veterans4diversity.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/nonprof-IT_icon.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"></a>
</div>
</html>
';
?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: If it's not needed, why include it? Should try to avoid redundant code.